# The form element is not rendered when used inside Telerik Tabstrip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

When I put a form inside a Telerik tabstrip, the form elements are not get rendered in the HTML. But input elements are rendered. This form is working fine outside tabstrip.

```
tabstrip.Add()
    .Text("Variants")
    .Content(() =>
    {
     %>
        <form action="#" id="form1" method="post">
            <input id="option" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="save" /></span>
        </form>
     <%
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to have that </span> in there without a matching tag?

Answer (score 0):

try to use something like this :

```
tabstrip.Add()
    .Text("Variants")
    .Content(
    {%><text>
     %>
        <form action="#" id="form1" method="post">
            <input id="option" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="save" />
        </form>
     <%
</text>

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem 
Kenod helper ignore first form if you put empty form and after that put your 
actual form it will ignore the first form and take your form

@{Html.Kendo().TabStrip().Name("TabStrip").TabPosition(Model.TabStripPosition).Items(items =>
        {
        foreach (var tab in Model.TabItems)
        {

```
        items.Add()
  .Text(tab.Title)
```

.Content(@
    @Html.Raw("")
    @using (Html.BeginForm("", "..","..", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "..." }))

```
{  @Html.Partial(tab.PartialView, tab.Model)}

    </text>
                        ).Selected(true)

        }

    }).Render();
```